# Rhetorical v grammatical

Tags: grammaticality

The sentence "you only can dream of the stars" - it's in a song lyric. I have tried singing it "you can only dream of the stars" which I think is semantically correct... but the emphasis sounds wrong, & having "only" as the second word just *sings* better. I would welcome opinions about just how unacceptable this is grammatically. 
Thanks, robb

Comment: *you only can dream of the stars* is grammatical. *you only...* could mean *you alone*, but *you only can dream* could mean *the only thing you can dream of is  the  stars*. In other words, it's ambiguous when taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Without a link to the song I can't know whether "stars" means "suns" or "famous people", I assume the first.

The second sentence could mean there is nothing else you can do with stars, for example:

> Can we reach the stars?
>
> You can only dream of the stars.

The first sentence could mean that in some circumstance, there is only one thing you can do:

> My lover has gone, how may I be consoled?
>
> You only can dream of the stars.

Just an angle - the above sentence is not very grammatical. A more grammatical interpretation could be:

> Only you can dream of the stars, nobody else.